# how the value is retained if we add it to some other object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

My question is how the value is retained if we insert it some other object.
Like ,if I have UILabel object which is already retained and I am setting its text from other NSString which is not retained.
My question is at some point in future if I change the value of that NSString ,will it get changed in UILabel also?
How the value of any object is retained if we add it to some other object?
Thanks,
Snehal Mehta

Answer (score 1):

With your label/string example, you have nothing to worry about for 2 reasons:

- NSStrings are immutable, so you can't change the value after assigning it to a label, unless you assign an NSMutableString instead, and later change it, but...
- String properties are typically implemented as `copy`, so when you assign a value, the receiving object makes its own internal copy of the string, meaning the original object has no relation to it.

So, properties that are of the copy type will not be affected if you make subsequent changes to the object. Other property types will just be a pointer to the original object, and so if that object is mutable then subsequent changes will alter the underlying property.